# Google Calendar Authorized JavaScript origins not working with multiple subdomains

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have implemented google calendar using javascript which is working fine for single subdomain. But my application is SAAS based and there will be multiple subdomain  and I am not able to enter wildcard in Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs.

So I have to enter the URL of all subdomain in google console which is a time consuming job.

So could anyone please suggest how to manage this.

Thanks,

Comment: "enter the URL of all subdomain in google console"  is the only option I am aware of.

Comment: what did you end up doing? did you find a solution?

Comment: not really...still in to do list :(

Comment: Facing same problem.Did you find solution?Its impossible to add all subdomains manually:(